# manipulate form input variable before post

Tags: php, validation

BEFORE hitting the submit button on a form, I need to send form variables and their values  into a php serialized array (name=>value).  And then upon post, I need to pass the array to a php function called modify($vararray).  For example:

```
<form action = "someaction.php" method="post"/>
  <input type="text" name="var1" id="var1" <br>
  <input type="text" name="var2" id="var2" <br>
  <?php

    (DO SOMETHING HERE TO CREATE A PHP SERIALIZED ARRAY OF NAME=>VALUE INTO $VARARRAY OF ALL PREVIOUS INPUT VARIABLES ABOVE)

    echo "input type=\"hidden\" name=\"modvar" id=\"modvar\" value=\"" . modify($vararray) . "\">\n";
  ?>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **JQuery.serializeArray()** for this here you can find an example:

URL: [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)

I hope this helps!